# How to access multiple attributes of a tag using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Say I have a HTML Tag `<span id="sample" value="type-2" data-type="haulted" encryption_stat="False"></span>`

I want to access values of its all attributes without using loops and list comprehension approach and I have a list of attributes to access `['data-type','encryption-stat','value']` of the span tag.

So basically I dont want to try this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = '<span id="sample" value="type-2" data-type="haulted" encryption_stat="false"></span>'
data = BeautifulSoup(s,'html.parser')
values = []
for i in ['data-type','encryption_stat','value']:
    values.append(data.find('span',id='sample').get(i))
```

Neither the list comprehension hack.

Is there anyway to achieve the objective?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use loops, you can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from operator import itemgetter

s = '<span id="sample" value="type-2" data-type="haulted" encryption_stat="false"></span>'
data = BeautifulSoup(s,'html.parser')


attrs = ['data-type','encryption_stat','value']
span = data.select_one('#sample')

i = itemgetter(*attrs)
print(i(span.attrs))
```

Prints:

```
('haulted', 'false', 'type-2')
```

---

Or: To handle missing attributes, you can do:

```
i = itemgetter(*(span.attrs.keys() & attrs))
print(i(span.attrs))
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with `element.attrs` and then find the value.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = '<span id="sample" value="type-2" data-type="haulted" encryption_stat="false"></span>'
data = BeautifulSoup(s,'html.parser')
item_attrs=data.find('span',id='sample').attrs
for item_attr in item_attrs:
    print(data.find('span',id='sample')[item_attr])
```

---

If you want to ignore any specific attribute use if clause.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = '<span id="sample" value="type-2" data-type="haulted" encryption_stat="false"></span>'
data = BeautifulSoup(s,'html.parser')
item_attrs=data.find('span',id='sample').attrs
for item_attr in item_attrs:
    if 'id' not in item_attr:
      print(data.find('span',id='sample')[item_attr])
```

Comment: Yes but I want to avoid using loops.

Answer (score 0):

Yes so I found a way to my answer, I thought it would be worth contributing here for all.

I tried it out using `map()`

```py
>>> list(map(data.find('span',id='sample').get,['data-type','encryption_stat','value']))
```

Another one was inspired from @KunduK's answer, using `map()`

```py
>>> all = data.find('span',id='sample').attrs
>>> list(map(all.__getitem__,['data-type','encryption_stat','value']))
```

This also worked for me.

Comment: I still want other answers if you find this answer is better then notify me